# Bash shell program starts C programs

Tags: c, bash

Is there a way for a `bash` shell program, that takes a command-line argument `x`, that will make `x` (C program) processes start?

.

Comment: As evidenced by the three completely different answers, this is a difficult-to-understand question. Please revise.

Comment: If you want to scheduled you command you can use `at` or `batch` command: `at` and `batch` read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
(( $# != 1 )) && echo "Usage: $0 num" && exit -1
for (( c=1; c<=$1; c++ ))
do
   ./run_c_program &
done
wait
```

- `$1` represents the first command line argument
- `$#` represents the number of arguments
- `$0` is the name of the script
- `run_c_program` is the executable of the c program
- with `&` the c programs are executed in the background
- with `wait` the scripts waits for the c programs to terminate (optional)

Answer (score 5):

It's fairly simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
```

If you want to pass the rest of the parameters as parameters to the function, do this:

```
$@
```

(i.e. `foo.sh echo hi` executes `echo hi`)

If you want to steal some parameters and pass others, use `shift`:

```
param1=$1
shift
echo $@ # contains parameters 2+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `system` function

```
system("./script.sh");
```